# how to add pre-calculated standard errors for both X and Y axis into a scatterplot in r?

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot, errorbar

Here's how my data look like:

## A tibble: 3 x 6

| box | `water(%)` | VWC_tube_avg | st_error_tube | VWC_sensor_avg | st_error_sensor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0.0110 | 0.00275 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 0.127 | 0.00429 | 0.0390 | 2.31e-18 |
| 1 | 30 | 0.383 | 0.0118 | 0.313 | 1.86e- 3 |

A quick explanation of the data: The data concerns the calibration of volumetric water content (VWC) soil sensors. In the table above we have the water % used for the calibration, the VWC presented in the test tubes followed by the standard error of the VWC of the tubes, the VWC of the sensors, and the correspondent previously calculated standard error.

Now I want to do a correlation scatterplot and add to each point (correlation) the correspondent standard error in the x-axis (st_error_tube) and y-axis (st_error_sensor).
The scatterplot correlation is done but the problem is the standard error bars which I can´t add to the scatterplot.

This is what I try, but without success:

```
ggplot(box1_1st, aes(VWC_tube_avg, VWC_sensor_avg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=st_error_tube, xmax=st_error_tube)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=st_error_sensor, ymax=st_error_sensor))
```

[image: This is the output from the code above]

Any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: Try using `geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin= VWC_tube_avg - st_error_tube, xmax= VWC_tube_avg + st_error_tube)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= VWC_sensor_avg - st_error_sensor, ymax= VWC_sensor_avg + st_error_sensor), position=position_dodge(.9))`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got something strange with the caps of the error bars faces the scatterplots.

Comment: What about `geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin= VWC_tube_avg - st_error_tube, xmax= VWC_tube_avg + st_error_tube)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= VWC_sensor_avg - st_error_sensor, ymax= VWC_sensor_avg + st_error_sensor), width=0.2)`?

Comment: The problem remains. I guess that a previous code command should be introduced before the command plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve that

```
library(ggplot2)

box1_1st <- read.table(text = "box  water   VWC_tube_avg    st_error_tube   VWC_sensor_avg  st_error_sensor
1   0   0.0110  0.00275 0   0
1   10  0.127   0.00429 0.0390  2.31e-18
1   30  0.383   0.0118  0.313   1.86e-3", header = T)


ggplot(box1_1st, aes(VWC_tube_avg, VWC_sensor_avg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin= VWC_tube_avg - st_error_tube, xmax= VWC_tube_avg + st_error_tube), height=0.01) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= VWC_sensor_avg - st_error_sensor, ymax= VWC_sensor_avg + st_error_sensor), width=0.01)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the help. the code works perfectly.